# Freestyle : problem with visibility

Tags: freestyle

I'm trying to use freestyle, to draw a cylinder that goes though a circle:

[image]

I'd like to add lines around the green part above like this:

[image]

I tried several freestyle parameters, including QI Range, Visible, Hidden, material boundaries, but I can't manage to do that...

Any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: For the missing **horizontal** line, see this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/383/16395 («*blender freestyle still does not detect edges at intersections*», but there are workarounds).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but enabling Render/Edges does not enable the good edge...

Answer (score 1):

Your issue comes from your object design : the cylinder and the circle should be in a single object + the circle should have a thickness + The circle should be an extrusion of a ring of the cylinder.

The idea is to create the cylinder, to add a loop on this cylinder and to extrude this loop to create the cicle.

Here is a full how to :

- Create a new project
- Delete the cube
- Add a cylinder : press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> then select *Mesh* and *Cylinder*
- Enter in edit mode (<kbd>TAB</kbd>)
- Press <kbd>S</kbd> then <kbd>Z</kbd> to enable Z scrolling
- Move the mouse to increase the hight of the cylinder.
- Press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to validate.
- Move the mouse cursor in the center of the cylinder
- Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to add a loop cut : a pink horizontal circle should appear at the middle of the cylinder like this :

[image: single pink circle]

- Scroll up the middle mouse button to have 2 pink circles like this :

[image]

- Press the left mouse button
- Move the mouse up to place the new ring
- Press the left mouse button to validate
- Enable the Face select mode (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> and select *Faces*)
- move the mouse cursor on a vertical edge of the middle ring you have just created
- Press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>RMB</kbd> : this ring should be selected (in orange) like this :

[image: circle ring selected]

- Press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude this ring and press <kbd>LMB</kbd> to validate immediatly (without moving the mouse)
- Press <kbd>S</kbd> to scall the ring and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to lock Z scalling
- Move your mouse to increase the diameter of the ring like this :

[image: circle ring extrusion]

- Press <kbd>LMB</kbd> to validate

To enable Freestyle :

- exit Edit Mode (<kbd>TAB</kbd>)
- in the Render panel, enable the *Freestyle* option
- launch render (<kbd>F12</kbd>)

Here is the result (after adding materials and reducing the circle thickness :

[image: final render]